# IOS display array of last 10 search string when click at UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm I'm developing an app with `UICollectionViewController`. I'm implementing a search feature with `UISearchController`. Here is what I have done:

```
var searchController: UISearchController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for article"
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

The problem is that how can we display list of 10 recent search string whenever user click on the `UISearchBar`? and detect if the user click on any previous search result (To reload collectionView to show filtered result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement it on your own. Whenever user click on the `UISearchBar` a delegate is called and you can show a `UITableView` attached beneath it listing 10 recent searches (if there's any).

When user searches something, add it to your maintained recent searches array/queue.

If user clicks on any recent searched item i.e. on `UITableView`, `didSelectRow` delegate will be called, you can search that string and reorganize the recent searches array/queue.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Also think about it. But the problem is I use UICollectionViewController and searchbar of UISerachController is place at the navigationItem. Don't know how can we place a suggestion tableview

Comment: Add a `UITableView` on top of `UICollectionView` with proper constraints and hide it initially, once `UISearchController` delegate calls on tapping it make the tableView visible.

Comment: But with UICollectionViewController, there is no way to add on top of collectionview. Maybe need to use UIViewController contain UICollectionView instead?

Comment: Yes, use `UIViewController`, add `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` on top of it. This would be much better approach. Using `UICollectionViewController` won't help in this case.